# Windows Custom Credential Provider using only OTP

Tags: windows, credential-providers

I want to develop Custom Credential Provider for windows login using only OTP without entering a password.
also, passwords should not be stored on the computer.
Is this possible? If possible, what should I refer to?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need write own [Authentication Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/authentication-packages) which accept your OTP as input